PowerBi use aggregate odata source (or specify type=open for odata query)
I am trying to add an aggregate odata query from Azure DevOps Analytics to PowerBi, the query (which works standalone) is as below. This returns a daily snapshot of test execution progress.
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{orgId}/{ProjectId}/_odata/v4.0-preview/TestPointHistorySnapshot?
$apply=
     filter(DateSK ge 20240301 and TestPlanId eq {PlanId})
     /groupby((DateSK,ResultOutcome),
      aggregate($count as TotalCount)
      )

This combines to
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJECT/_odata/v4.0-preview/TestPointHistorySnapshot?%24apply=filter%28DateSK+ge+20240301+and+TestPlanId+eq+PLANID%29+%2Fgroupby%28%28DateSK%2CResultOutcome%29%2C+aggregate%28%24count+as+TotalCount%29+%29

PowerBi successfully executes the flattened URL, but refuses to parse the response with the error message:
OData: The property 'TotalCount' does not exist on type 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Analytics.Model.TestPointHistorySnapshot'. Make sure to only use
property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.

Selecting the include open type columns option makes no difference. Is there anyway I can specify the type as open via the query?

I found a way to do this using a data source type of web; which generates the following code for the datasource
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJECT/_odata/v4.0-preview/TestPointHistorySnapshot?%24apply=filter%28DateSK+ge+20240101+and+TestSuite%2FTestPlanId+eq+00000%29+%2Fgroupby%28+%28DateSK%29%2C+aggregate%28+%24count+as+TotalCount%2C+cast%28ResultOutcome++eq+%27Passed%27%2C+Edm.Int32%29+with+sum+as+Passed%2C+cast%28ResultOutcome++eq+%27Failed%27%2C+Edm.Int32%29+with+sum+as+Failed%2C+cast%28ResultOutcome+eq+%27Blocked%27%2C+Edm.Int32%29+with+sum+as+Blocked%2C+cast%28ResultOutcome+eq+%27NotApplicable%27%2C+Edm.Int32%29+with+sum+as+NotApplicable%2C+cast%28ResultOutcome+eq+%27None%27%2C+Edm.Int32%29+with+sum+as+NotExecuted%2C+cast%28ResultOutcome+ne+%27None%27%2C+Edm.Int32%29+with+sum+as+Executed+%29+%29")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Source}),
    #"Expanded value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "value"),
    #"Expanded value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded value", "value", { "DateSK", "Executed", "NotExecuted", "NotApplicable", "Blocked", "Failed", "Passed", "TotalCount"}, { "value.DateSK", "value.Executed", "value.NotExecuted", "value.NotApplicable", "value.Blocked", "value.Failed", "value.Passed", "value.TotalCount"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded value1",{ {"value.DateSK", Int64.Type}, {"value.Executed", Int64.Type}, {"value.NotExecuted", Int64.Type}, {"value.NotApplicable", Int64.Type}, {"value.Blocked", Int64.Type}, {"value.Failed", Int64.Type}, {"value.Passed", Int64.Type}, {"value.TotalCount", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"


Thanks for much for your sharing, glad to know it's resolved.
